# How can I check the temperature of a GoPro?

Tags: gopro, heat

I've noticed that my GoPro 10 tends to overheat. How can I check the temperature of the GoPro? I don't want to wait until it shut down with an overheat message.

Comment: I'm no expert but this kind of indicates to me a deeper problem. I assume not all GoPro users are experiencing the same thing. Why is your camera/setup different?

Comment: @osullic GoPros notoriously overheat.

Comment: Seems [this article](https://havecamerawilltravel.com/gopro/gopro-getting-hot/) confirms what you say. I have a GoPro Hero 5 and it never feels hot to the touch.

Answer (score 1):

Search "Temperature sticker" on Amazon. You possiby want something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FVOQL84) (it should be reversible, those that are not tell you the max temperature ever reached).

But these will give you the temperature of the outer body, not the temperature of the components inside, so you'll need some margin. The temperature difference between the component and the outside is however fairly constant. The computation is very similar to Ohm's law, if the components-to-enclosing has a thermal resistance of 2°C/W and the inside produces 5W of heat, then the components will be `5 × 2 = 10°C` hotter than the body, and assuming a 4°C/W resistance between body and ambient air, the body itself will be `5 × 4 = 20°C` hotter that the ambient air (so your components are 30°C hotter that your local temperature)(numbers in this example are strictly arbitrary...).